# Exchange 2010 SP3: 4.3.1 Insufficient system resources

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, exchange-hybrid

We have Office 365 with a hybrid deployment. Our on-premise server is relaying email directly out to the web (not via EOP). `domain-a.com` is an accepted domain on our on-premise server; `domain-b.com` is not.

The issue we have had was that the on-premise server was a bit low on space on the C: volume and the transport server was rejecting emails with a from address of `domain-b.com`, but not `domain-a.com`. The error message received was:

```
send-mailmessage : Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.3.1 Insufficient system resources   
    At line:1 char:1                                                                                               
    + send-mailmessage -to me@domain-a.com -Subject test -from email@domain-b.com                       
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                             
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage],SmtpException                                                                                                  
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Once I had cleared down the log files in IIS, email was successfully relayed for both domains. **What could be the explanation for this?** I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: This article may help explain...? [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201658(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201658(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Backpressure is caused by low systems resources, which you know that you had. It causes SMTP sessions to be rejected or delayed.

Advice: Move all the logs (IIS, transport protocols, etc) off the system volume.

Comment: I understand what the solution was in general, but it doesn't explain why it works for one and not the other.

Comment: Perhaps they came in on different connectors that have different rules? I don't know, you need to tell us more about your environment.